# URL encoding in swift (posting username and password)

Tags: swift

My code is below written in objective C.

```
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[self.txtUsername text],[self.txtPassword text]];
           NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);
           NSURL *Url=[NSURL URLWithString:getLoginURL];
          NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
           NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
           NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
```

I would like to write this code in swift.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: This is not a code conversion tool here... you must show some efforts.

Comment: I could not find documentation regarding NSUrl and NSData usage in swift.

Comment: Because you don't really need any.  There's a fairly straight-forward translation of method calling conventions.  Download the swift book from iTunes book store and have at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let post = "username=\(self.txtUsername.text)&password=\(self.txtPassword.text)"
println("PostData: \(post)")
let url = NSURL(getLoginURL)
let postData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
let postLength = "\(postData.length)"
let request = NSMutableURLRequest()
```